# maximum dynamic partitions in Hive limit

Tags: hive

I am using dynamic partitions in my query. I get the following error:-

```
ERROR Failed with exception Number of dynamic partitions created is 9000, which is more than 5000
```

I know there are multiple posts on this topic. Setting higher value for `hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions` should take care of it. My question is different. I am trying to understand the exact meaning of the error. Is this limit only for a single job i.e. a single job can't create more than 5000 dynamic partitions? Or it's a table level limit that a table which has dynamic partitions defined on it, can't have more than 5000 of these partitions in total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit is for single job and not for the table.
You can look at Hive tests to verify this.

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/8dc40db5f90ca9491b643f70e2344decbd2ad8f5/ql/src/test/queries/clientnegative/dyn_part1.q

Comment: so there is no table level limit as such?

Comment: Yes as far as I know there is no limit as such. There will be performance implications if you're reading many partitions. Hive stores metadata in RDBMS so that should be fast enough and you should have enough resources in Hadoop cluster.